# change text in boxes of confusion matrix plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the [`plot_confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix) function that is available in scikitlearn 0.22. However, I am having an issue where the text values in the box cannot be seen for one of my boxes because all the text colors seem to be set at the same value as that box. This is the case no matter which `cmap` I select. Incidentally that value is also the lowest one. This does not happen in the [example they provide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py). How can I change the box text color so that all the values can be seen clearly? I do not want to use `seaborn` like has been suggested in many of the other solutions unless I have to.

A reproducible example is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix

np.random.seed(3851)

# import some data to play with
bc = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X = bc.data
y = bc.target
class_names = bc.target_names

# Split the data into a training set and a test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
np.random.shuffle(y_test)

# Run classifier, using a model that is too regularized (C too low) to see
# the impact on the results
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.0001).fit(X_train, y_train)

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
titles_options = [("Confusion matrix, without normalization", None),
                  ("Normalized confusion matrix", 'true')]
for title, normalize in titles_options:
    disp = plot_confusion_matrix(classifier, X_test, y_test,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                 normalize=normalize)
    disp.ax_.set_title(title)

    print(title)
    print(disp.confusion_matrix)

plt.show()
```

[image: Confusion matrix]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have hit upon a bug. I've submitted [the issue on github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15920) and have offered a possible fix.

Basically, the color of the text is chosen based on whether the value at above or below a threshold, which should be the middle of the range of the cmap. But I believe there is a problem in the way the threshold is calculated, and so all you values in your normalized example end up below the threshold and are drawn with the lighter color.

If you want a temporary fix, you can modify a file in your installation of scikit-learn `.../site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py` on line 96 should read

`thresh = cm.min()+(cm.max() - cm.min()) / 2.` instead of `thresh = (cm.max() - cm.min()) / 2.`

```
===================================================================
--- metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py   (date 1576701552905)
+++ metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py   (date 1576701552905)
@@ -93,7 +93,7 @@
                 values_format = '.2g'

             # print text with appropriate color depending on background
-            thresh = (cm.max() - cm.min()) / 2.
+            thresh = cm.min()+(cm.max() - cm.min()) / 2.
             for i, j in product(range(n_classes), range(n_classes)):
                 color = cmap_max if cm[i, j] < thresh else cmap_min
                 self.text_[i, j] = ax.text(j, i,
```

Comment: thanks for this, changing it in the file did work for me as a temporary solution.